# Angular TreeGrid (ej2 syncfusion) connection with backend API data not rendered

Tags: angular, syncfusion, treegrid

Does anybody use [ej2 syncfusion](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/bootstrap5/treegrid/treegrid-overview/) angular UI components?
I am trying to connect my backend API with their TreeGrid component,
The connection works fine, the request gives data successfully, but the TreeGrid isn't rendered any data from BE side.
Here are my code examples;
in component:

```
        this.tableData = new DataManager({
        url: `http://localhost:3000/table-data/? 
        &dataId=${this.storageService.getTableDataId()}`, adaptor: new  
        WebApiAdaptor, 
        crossDomain: true })
```

in view:

```
<ng-container  *ngIf="tableData">
  <ejs-treegrid #treegrid [dataSource]='tableData'
                height='100vh'
                [pageSettings]="{pageSize: 30, pageCount: 1}"
                [enableInfiniteScrolling]="true"
                (actionBegin)="getNewPage($event)"
                [treeColumnIndex]='1'
                allowPaging='false'>

      <e-columns>
          <e-column
            field='serialNumber'
            headerText='serialNumber'
            width='120'
            textAlign='Center'>
          </e-column>
          <e-column
            field='description'
            headerText='description'
            width='50'>
          </e-column>
          <e-column
            field='companyName'
            headerText='companyName'
            width='50'>
          </e-column>
          <e-column
            field='employeeName'
            headerText='employeeName'
            width='100'>
          </e-column>
        </e-columns>
      </ejs-treegrid>
    </ng-container>
```

data what I send from BE:

```
{
count: number;
dataId: string:
rows: object[];
}
```

Comment: have you find any solution for that? facing same issue.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not figured out totally, because this library didn't attract me for use in my project, but I had written to their support team and they have recommended using UrlAdaptor instead WebApiAdaptor also they told me that for getting data with UrlAdaptor we have to use a POST request. And in response data, we should have  fields  'count' and  'result' **I used 'rows' maybe it was the main problem**, also I recommend considering interface DataResult in their library seems in these interface been described all mandatory fields what we should send from backend

Comment: Thanks for Response. Really Appreciate.